# Evaluating $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to evaluate $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin z}dz$. Here's what I have thus far:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{5-3 \sin z}dz&= \frac{1}{3} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\frac{5}{3}- \sin z}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\frac{10i-3e^{i z}+3e^{-i z}}{6i}} \\
&=2 i \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{10i - 3e^{iz}+3e^{-iz}}dz\\
&= 2 i \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{10i - 3e^{iz}+3e^{-iz}} \frac{e^{iz}}{e^{iz}}dz\\
&=2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{10iu-3u^2+3} du&& \text{where $u=e^{iz}$, $du=ie^{iz}dz$}\\
&= -2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{3(u+3i)(u+\frac{i}{3})} du
\end{align*}

but I get stuck here, Am I on the right path? Also I don't think that

$$-3(u+3i)(u+\frac{i}{3})=10iu-3u^2+3$$

Im off by a negative for the $10iu$. If possible, when helping use the formula for $\sin z$:

$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$
Thanks in advance. (PS- why would someone downvote this? Its clearly showing I have work shown and have made an attempt at a solution!)

Comment: As $z$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$, $u=e^{iz}$ traces out the unit circle $\Gamma$ in the complex plane. So your real integral is now a contour integral and you can proceed with the residue theorem.

Comment: @user170231 so I only need to calculate the integral for the point $\frac{i}{3}$ as the other point lies outside of the circle?

Comment: @b00nheT can I then use the Cauchy integral formula for $a=\frac{i}{3}$

Comment: If you're not expected to use complex analysis to solve this, try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 3):

The $z$ variable in your integral is actually an angle (and perhaps should be better denoted with $\theta$ or $\phi$). Your integral can be transformed into
$$
\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{-\frac{2}{3}dz}{(z-3i)(z-\frac{1}{3}i)}
$$
through substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$. This integral is the same as in the OP, but in a more standard and formal form, since generalizations from real-valued to complex-valued functions should be performed with care, especially for non-analytical functions.

Comment: so to evaluate this integral, it suffices to evaluate using Cauchy's integral formula for the point $z=\frac{i}{3}$ ? But then I get $\frac{3 \pi}{2 i}$.

Comment: You perhaps forgot to multiply the summation of all the residues in $2\pi i$, as the theorem states.

Comment: isn't the residue for $z=3i$ just zero though ?

Comment: You need not to calculate the residue for $z=3i$, since it falls outside $|z|=1$. Only the residue in $z=\frac{i}{3}$ is important.

Comment: I end up with $-2(2 \pi i)\frac{1}{\frac{i}{3}-3i}=-4 \pi i \frac{-3}{8i}=\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ and its supposed to be $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Actually, I considered $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\frac{5}{3}-\sin z}dz$ in my answer. I corrected it.

Comment: @MyMathYourMath, your calculations are correct and the same answer of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is obtained.

Comment: did the $3$ under the $2$ come from pulling it out of $-(u-3i)(3u-i)$?

Comment: Exactly. I factored $\frac{5}{3}-\sin z=\frac{5}{3}-\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$ in the denominator in the original answer, while I should have factored ${5}-{3}\sin z=5-3\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\tan(\frac{z}{2})$, $\sin z=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$ and $dz=\frac{2dt}{t^2+1}$ and thinking the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{(t-\frac{3}{5})^2+(\frac{4}{5})^2}dt=\left.\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{5t-3}{4}\right)\right\rvert_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$